# Linear Regression with gradient desent not giving correct results

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

Linear regression with gradient descent is giving different result on the same dataset compared to sklearn.

Want to know why is that so. Is it the problem of local minima

The dataset is as follows

```
ht  wt
63  127
64  121
66  142
69  157
69  162
71  156
71  169
72  165
73  181
75  208
```

Sklearn is computing intercept as -266.53439537 and coefficient as 6.13758146

whereas gradient descent is giving intercept as -1.49087014 and coeff as 2.3239637

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cost (m,b , data_size):
    x = IN
    y = OUT
    totalError = 0
    for i in range (data_size):
    x = IN[i]
    y = OUT[i]
    totalError += ((m*x + b) - y) ** 2
    return totalError/ float(data_size)


def compute_gradient(X , Y, theta_1 ,theta_0 , N, learning_rate):

    gradient_theta_0 = 0
    gradient_theta_1 = 0

    #print (X.shape, Y.shape, N)

    Y_pred = theta_1*X + theta_0

    gradient_theta_1 = ((-2/N) * sum(X * (Y - Y_pred)))
    gradient_theta_0 = ((-2/N) * sum(Y - Y_pred))


    #print (gradient_theta_0 , gradient_theta_1, gradient_theta_0 * 
    learning_rate, gradient_theta_1 * learning_rate)    
    new_theta_0 = theta_0 - (gradient_theta_0 * learning_rate)
    new_theta_1 = theta_1 - (gradient_theta_1 * learning_rate)

    return (new_theta_1,new_theta_0)

IN = np.array([63 , 64, 66, 69, 69, 71, 71, 72, 73, 75])
OUT = np.array([127,121,142,157,162,156,169,165,181,208])

X = IN[:,np.newaxis]
Y = OUT[:,np.newaxis]

iterations       = 10000
initial_theta_0  = 0 
initial_theta_1  = 0
learning_rate    = 0.00001  
theta_0          = initial_theta_0
theta_1          = initial_theta_1

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
cost_history = []

for i in range (iterations):
    #print ("iteration {} m {} b {}".format(i, theta_1, theta_0))
    [theta_1, theta_0] = compute_gradient(X , Y , theta_1 ,theta_0, 
data_size, learning_rate) 
    totalError = cost (theta_1,theta_0, data_size)
    #print (totalError)
    cost_history.append (totalError)

ax.plot(range(iterations),cost_history,'b.')    

print ("iteration {} m {} b {}".format(i, theta_1, theta_0))

reg_line = [(theta_1 * x) + theta_0 for x in IN]

lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X, Y)

print ("SKLEARN coeff {}".format(lm.coef_))
print ("SKLEARN intercept {}".format(lm.intercept_))

#reg_line = [(lm.coef_[0] * x) + lm.intercept_ for x in IN]

ax3.plot (IN, reg_line , color='red')  
plt.show()

print ("SKLEARN coeff {}".format(lm.coef_))
print ("SKLEARN intercept {}".format(lm.intercept_)) 

RESULTS
iteration 99999 m [2.3239637] b [-1.49087014]
SKLEARN coeff [[6.13758146]]
SKLEARN intercept [-266.53439537]
```

Comment: Please make the example fully reproducible by showing *exactly* how you have used the code (both yours & sklearn's) to arrive at the reported coefficients).

Comment: Added the full code

Answer (score 1):

You have taken bad initial conditions (0,0) and fallen into a local minimum close to that point. More intuitive initial conditions are based on maxima and minima of ht and wt, i.e.

```
initial_theta_0 = np.min(Y)+np.min(X)*(np.min(Y)-np.max(Y))/(np.max(X)-np.min(X)) #-335.75
initial_theta_1 = (np.max(Y)-np.min(Y))/(np.max(X)-np.min(X)) # 7.25    

#initial_theta_0 = 121+63*(121-208)/(75-63) # -335.75
#initial_theta_1 = (208-121)/(75-63) # 7.25
```

Comment: Thank you  Grzegorz. But least square is a convex function. So is it not independent of the initial value. Whatever initial value we choose it should converge ?

Comment: Yes, but with your data, there are many local minima and only one global. Starting from "my" initial conditions many of those local minima can be left behind. Using learning_rate=0.0002 and number of iterations=999999 you can obtain m [6.45397547] b [-288.52353716] still going towards the value found by sklearn.

Comment: I assumed that your value is checked by you as the minimum, but it was a wrong assumption - increasing the number of iterations you can slowly but still go towards the value found by sklearn.

Comment: @AjoyDas It appears you have discovered the drawbacks of unsupervised gradient descents, congratulations! :-) Just picture yourself going skiing in the Alps; if you descent the steep slope without any steering input, will you automatically reach the bottom of the hill, or rather get stuck somewhere along the trail in a local minimum (a ditch) or maximum (a tree)? If you'd wait long enough, could you eventually end up at sea level (X=0,Y=0) ? :-)

Comment: So basically before doing gradient descent we need to check the data first to check the local minina and accordingly set the initial values. or How do we do it ?

Comment: There are a few aspects. Primo, a mathematician's look at the given model and data enables to obtain good initial conditions. Good in the sense of close to the global minimum of loss function and needed fewer iterations than any other ones. Secundo, checking the value of loss function you can find if you have reached a minimum (a kind of early stopping). Tertio, starting from a few different initial conditions and/or different learning rate you can eliminate a case of reaching an accidentally bad local minimum instead of much better or global one.